# Celery prefork error when start worker: request_stack is None

Tags: python, celery

Recently, I'm encountering when starting workers with prefork mode in Celery (`5.2.3`). Here is its stack trace

```
[2022-01-06 00:56:18,535: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Process ForkPoolWorker-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bryan/workplace/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 327, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/Users/bryan/workplace/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/bryan/workplace/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 289, in __call__
    self.after_fork()
  File "/Users/bryan/workplace/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 421, in after_fork
    self.initializer(*self.initargs)
  File "/Users/bryan/workplace/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/concurrency/prefork.py", line 75, in process_initializer
    task.__trace__ = build_tracer(name, task, app.loader, hostname,
  File "/Users/bryan/workplace/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 361, in build_tracer
    push_request = request_stack.push
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'push'
```

I understand that `request_stack` is None hence it causes an error but I still don't know why request_stack is `None`. I would like to ask for an idea to fix this

Other info:

```
celery@D v5.2.3 (dawn-chorus)

macOS-12.1-x86_64-i386-64bit 2022-01-06 00:56:18

[config]
.> app:         app:0x103a39970
.> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
.> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
.> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
.> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)

[queues]
.> queues_DISTRIBUTED_QUEUE exchange=queues_DISTRIBUTED_QUEUE(direct) key=queues_DISTRIBUTED_QUEUE
```

Comment: Could you please also paste how do you run your Celery worker (the entire command line)?

Comment: `celery -A run.celery worker -n D -c 1 -Q queues_DISTRIBUTED_QUEUE --loglevel info`

Comment: "Celery no longer officially supports Windows since Celery version 4. x"

Comment: i'm running on macOS though

Comment: Try some different version of Celery. Maybe you are hitting some bug... Try latest Celery 4.x perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

For celery version 5.2.x, switch the approach to registering your class-based task accordingly:

```py
# app.tasks.register(CustomTask())  # broken, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'push'
app.register_task(CustomTask())  # fixed, no error
```

Source: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/7173#issuecomment-1206584450

---

> Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
from celery import Celery, Task

app = Celery()

class CustomTask(Task):
    name = "custom_task"
    def run(self):
        return 'hello'

app.tasks.register(CustomTask())  # broken, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'push'
# app.register_task(CustomTask())  # fixed, no error
```

> The bug/regression appears for the first time in [v5.2.0b1 and is not present in 5.1.2](https://github.com/celery/celery/compare/v5.1.2...v5.2.0b1). Again it only applies to class-based tasks, and it has everything to do with what method is used to register the task.